# How to use json put as append

Tags: java, json

I have to extract from a database some fields that mean the details of some stores from the same locality. I need them in json format for the output. Here is my code:

```
    JSONObject result =  null;
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT STORE, LOCALITY, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, ADDRESS, SCHEDULE"
                    + " FROM STORE_LOCATIONS"
                    + " WHERE LOCALITY = ?";

    String connectionName = properties.getProperty(JNDI_NAME);
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = getJNDIConnection(connectionName);
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        pstmt.setString(1, locality);
        resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            result = new JSONObject();
            do {

                JSONObject jsonStore = new JSONObject();

                jsonStore.put("store", resultSet.getString(1));
                jsonStore.put("locality", resultSet.getString(2));
                jsonStore.put("latitude", resultSet.getDouble(3));
                jsonStore.put("longitude", resultSet.getDouble(4));
                jsonStore.put("address", resultSet.getString(5));
                jsonStore.put("schedule", resultSet.getString(6));

                logger.debug("[{}] jsonStore={}", methodName, jsonStore);
                result.append("stores", jsonStore);
            } while(resultSet.next());
        }
    }
```

After i run this code, my result is in a json array, with the index i give in result.append.Like this:

> {
>     "stores": [
>       {
>         "schedule": "",
>         "store": "Yet another store",
>         "address": "",
>         "locality": "Locality one",
>         "longitude":"" ,
>         "latitude": ""
>       },
>       {
>         "schedule": "",
>         "store": "Another store",
>         "address": "",
>         "locality": "Locality one",
>         "longitude":"" ,
>         "latitude": ""
>       },
>       {
>         "schedule": "",
>         "store": "One store",
>         "address": "",
>         "locality": "Locality one",
>         "longitude":"" ,
>         "latitude": ""
>       }
>     ]
>   }

What i need is a single object, which would be the result of result.put. But if i write it that way, it only gives me one single record, instead of three for the specified locality.
Basicly, without the square bracket.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates a JSON array containing the fields of each record in the database.This is how you have to collect the data for multiple rows and map the JSON array with id as stores. If you want to create a single JSON object to store data of multiple records, it would be tedious because you have to create the keys in JSON object unique. For that, you have to add an identifier to create the unique key for every field in every iteration like this below

```
{ "stores": { "schedule1": "", "store1": "Yet another store", "address1": "", "locality1": "Locality one", "longitude1":"" , "latitude1": "" }, { "schedule2": "", "store2": "Another store", "address2": "", "locality2": "Locality one", "longitude2":"" , "latitude2": "" }, { "schedule3": "", "store3": "One store", "address3": "", "locality3": "Locality one", "longitude3":"" , "latitude": "" } }
```

Please see the identifier (that should be added for every field ) Ex: schedule1 - 1 is added to make it unique property of JSON object. This will become more difficult while retrieving values from the JSON object. I would recommend not to switch to this logic

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Octopus. So you say that the format that i received back is ok?